# GWT/Gin creating class with @Inject annotation in constructor

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin

Let's say I have a class

```
public class Foo{
   @Inject
   public Foo(MessageBus messageBus, SomeServiceAsync service){
      ...
   }
...
```

I have some doubt on how I would construct such a class, given that the constructor parameters are to be injected. Or must I somehow also get an instance of the Foo class through Gin (is that the case anyway for injection to take place)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. You must get all `Foo`s from Gin if you want them to have their constuctors injected. To get a `Foo` from Gin, you need to either have it injected into something else, or use a [`Ginjector`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial#Step_2._Defining_the_Ginjector). Usually you'll get only one class' instances (or a small number of classes' instances) from a `Ginjector`, and rely on Gin to inject all of their  dependencies, and their dependencies' dependencies, and so on.
The [Gin Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial) is a great place to start.

Comment: Thanks. For me, the Gin tutorial got me started, but if you have never used DI, it is a bit rough on the edges, it seems to assume knowledge of Guice. I am trying to refactor a 600+ classes application, this is not going to be fun...

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I used Gin before Guice too, and found the same. Good luck with the refactor: your team will love it, even if you don't  ;) .